# Freebase domain and types

Tags: freebase, mql

Is there a way using MQL to list all the types belong to a Freebase domain and to list all properties belonging to a type e.g. Given the domain "Computer" I would like to list all "types belonging to it as shown in:

http://www.freebase.com/computer?data=

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983715/list-all-freebase-domains-with-mql-query-or-api-call

Answer (score 0):

The following query returns Types and the Domains they belong. The result has pairs of Type - Domain. There is also a filter to keep only the domains in the `/category/commons` (see [List all Freebase Domains with MQL query or API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983715/list-all-freebase-domains-with-mql-query-or-api-call)).

```
[{
  "id": null,
  "type": "/type/type",
  "name": null,
  "domain": {
    "id": null,
    "name": null
  },
  "ns0:domain": {
    "!/freebase/domain_category/domains": {
      "id": "/category/commons"
    }
  }
}]
```